# Trim string from behind and convert to integer

Tags: c#, .net

I have string for example

```
var str = "1,203cars";
```

I want to convert this number to Integer (*to remove this strange comma separator*) and to remove cars. I know  I should be using `String.Trim()` method but I don't know how to trim from behind and remove cars and convert `1,203` to `1203` without losing data.

Comment: Is it always "cars"? is it always 4 digits with a comma in that position?

Comment: yes, it's always cars, although number can be more or less than 4 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get the number from the beginning of the string (which will leave out any number later in the string), then remove the separator.

Example:

```
string str = "1,203cars then 703bikes";

string num = Regex.Match(str, @"^[\d,]+").Value.Replace(",", String.Empty);
```

Then you can parse the string:

```
int n = Int32.Parse(num);
```

Explanation of the regular expression

```
^      =   Matches the beginning of the string
[]     =   Matches a set of characters
\d     =   Matches a digit
[\d,]  =   Matches a digit or a comma
+      =   Repeats the previos match one or more times
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `\d` will also match non-Arabic numerals (like 五) so `[0-9]` might be better in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using a little Linq trick:

```
var result = int.Parse(new string(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
```

Or, since char.IsDigit returns true for all unicode digits, here is more proper solution:

```
var numbers = new [] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

var result = int.Parse(new string(str.Where(numbers.Contains).ToArray()));
```

Comment: @leppie why ? because char.Digit returns true for all unicode digits?

Comment: No, because `char.IsDigit` returns boolean... I wont even attempt to figure out what the rest does. Edit: Did you mean `Where`, that would make sense ;p

Comment: Oh, `select` should be `where`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var str = "1,203cars";   
 var newStr = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(str.replace(",",""), @"\d+").Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's always exactly "cars", you can just remove the last 4 characters, then replace commas with the empty string:

```
int.Parse(str.Remove(str.Length-4).Replace(",",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = "1,20.3cars";
    str = str.Replace(",", "");
    var num = int.Parse(new string(str.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));

    Console.WriteLine(num);
```